# Why does the getFirst() in ConcurrentHashMap declare an array variable referencing the `table` field?

Tags: java

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.Segment.getFirst%28int%29

in line 340:

```
 HashEntry<K,V>  getFirst(int hash) { 
     HashEntry<K,V>[] tab = table; 
     return tab[hash & (tab.length - 1)]; 
 }
```

why do we need a `tab` here?  why doesn't it just write the following statement instead?

```
return table[hash & (table.length - 1)];
```

Comment: What type is `table`?

Comment: Maybe the coder thought that accessing a local variable twice was more efficient that accessing the instance variable twice. That might be his/her coding style. Or perhaps it is guarding against the `table` field being reassigned between the two uses of `tab` in the next line. Ask whoever wrote the code.

Comment: I can not see such method in [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Comment: @Jens http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.Segment.getFirst%28int%29

Comment: @Lily, this is not the official `ConcurrentHashMap` code. OpenJDK is an open source version of the JDK, in the standard JDK this method doesn't exist. And yes, you should ask whoever wrote the code, if they didn't leave a comment we can't know what was in their mind when they wrote it

Comment: @BackSlash the getFirst method also exists in the oracle JDK (version 6, as Lily has linked). In Java 8 it seems to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The data will be inconsistant if table is changed in the interval of `.length` method and `table[]`.

Comment: if table is changed, so is tab, they are referencing the same object.

Comment: @Lily No. the reference gets **copied** to the new variable, so the change doesn't affect the "copy".  It's the same object, but the reference gets copied. It affects the original one only if you change its contents. See this demo: http://ideone.com/7R1Pp4